# Synchronizing one subtitle file to another

Tags: ruby, parsing, time, synchronization, subtitle

Both subtitle files are in `srt` format. One of them is already synchronized, so time codes are good. I assumed that only a linear transformation need to be applied on the time codes (`y=a*x+b`, where `x` is the timecode of the subtitle), so I want to look for `a` and `b`. I need to select two line pairs from each files, which will be the basis of resynchronization.

I looked for words which appear in both of the subtitle text, chose two of them whose distances are maximum with respect to time. Then I calculated `a` and `b` solving a linear equation `y1=a*x1+b`, `y2=a*x2+b`, where `y1` is timecode of the subtitle line already synchronized, and `x1` is the timecode of the subtitle line which needs to be synchronized yet. This is why I need two pairs of subtitle lines. However this approach doesn't work in every case, for example when those proper nouns are also translated to the given language (for example Chinese).

What other approaches should I follow to solve this problem?